# Random sample from selection

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have a selection in vector point. I would like to do random sample from it. I am using qgis to do it.

Here is my selection code:

```
selection=layers_canvas[0].getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(u'"fitofissio" ILIKE \'%Vereda%\''))
layers_canvas[0].setSelectedFeatures([s.id() for s in selection])
```

I don't know how to do it. The result of select is on class and it isn't able to use ramdom.sample in it. I tried to do my random sample with this function.

Comment: If `selection` is an array of length `n` and you want a sample of size `z`, then can you get a sample of indices using `sample(xrange(n), z)` and simply select those indices from `selection`?

Comment: My variable selection is a class. See the result above:
>>>type(selection)
<class 'qgis._core.QgsFeatureIterator'>

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want a sample of z elements from n.

As `selection` is an iterator try this (there's probably a more pythonic way of doing this so feel free to edit):

```
sel_sample = []
zsample = random.sample(xrange(n), z)
for i in xrange(n):
    if i in zsample:
        sel_sample.append(next())
    else:
        next()
```

Comment: My pythonic way..  `sel_sample = [i for i in xrange(n) if i in zsample]`

Comment: Not sure that complies with _Simple is better than complex. Readability counts. Sparse is better than dense._ while it does say _Flat is better than nested._ :) Regardless, is it possible to fit the necessary `next()` portions in the list comprehension?

Comment: I prefer to think of it as `Beautiful is better than ugly`.  I am so used to nested for loops that I just love the flat structure of that. I can see readability problems for those who haven't used it before, but it is a nice *optional* way to do things.

Comment: I like it. Is it possible to add the `sel_sample.append(next())` and `next()` code to your list comprehension syntax?

Comment: Oh..my mistake.  I am only appending the current iteration to the list.  I finally looked up the `next()` function and that code doesn't do that.  I guess I skimmed this a little too quick.  I tried some variations to include `next()` in the loop, but I didn't see a way.